# Div won't show() using jquery

Tags: jquery, class, html, hide, show

I got a really wierd problem. If you click the class:"change_btn" i want to show a specific div. But the only one working is the password form (passwordFC). When i click the other buttons nothing is visible. They have content. How can this be?

I've tried for hours , any help is appreciated.

Best regards
Jimmy

**Jquery**

```
jQuery(function($) {

    /* Make the password form show first as standard */
    $(".settingsFC").hide();
    $(".passwordFC").show();

    /* Function that shows the right form when clicking the buttons */

    $(".change_btn").click(function() { 

        $choosenForm = "." + $(this).attr("title"); 

        /* Remove the style on the other buttons */
        $(".settingButton").css('background-color','#ebeaea');
        $(".settingButton").css('font-weight','normal');

        /* Add style to clicked button */
        $(this).css('background-color','#e0e0e0');
        $(this).css('font-weight','bold');

        /* Hide the other containers, if i remove this they show when clicking. */
        $(".settingsFC").hide();

        /* Tried this one as well, didnt work */
        //$(".settingsFC:not(."+$choosenForm+")").hide();

        /* Show the right container */
        $($choosenForm).show();

    });
});
```

**Html**

```
<div title="passwordFC"  class="settingButton px10 change_btn firstSettingsChoice"> INLOGGNING </div>
<div title="personalFC" class="settingButton px10 change_btn"> PERSONLIGT </div>
<div title="paymentFC"  class="settingButton px10 change_btn"> BETALNINGSPLAN </div>
<div title="cloudFC"  class="settingButton px10 change_btn"> CLOUD INSTÄLLNINGAR </div>


<div class="settingsFC passwordFC">
    <?php include("includes/changeSettings/changePassword.php"); ?>
</div> <!-- changePassword -->

<div class="settingsFC personalFC">
    <?php include("includes/changeSettings/changePersonal.php"); ?>
</div> <!-- changePersonal -->

<div class="settingsFC paymentFC">
    <?php include("includes/changeSettings/changePayment.php"); ?>
</div> <!-- changePayment -->

<div class="settingsFC cloudFC">
    <?php include("includes/changeSettings/changeCloud.php"); ?>
</div> <!-- changeCloud -->
```

Comment: It looks like it's working... http://jsfiddle.net/ptkdU/ Maybe the PHP code you're including is breaking things?

Comment: Works fine for me. [See here](http://jsfiddle.net/XDfzm/)

Comment: You guys are right, i removed the php code and now everything works fine. Very strange, the include documents only has a form. I shall look into it, thanks!

Comment: If the included code has invalid HTML (e.g. a closing `</div>` tag), it can cause unexpected behavior.

Answer (score -1):

Here's what you need to do. Working fiddle (with PHP stuff removed for testing) - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/58jMM/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  /* Make the password form show first as standard */
  $(".settingsFC").hide();
  //$(".passwordFC").show();


  /* Function that shows the right form when clicking the buttons */

  $(".change_btn").click(function() { 

         var choosenForm = "." + $(this).attr("title"); 

         /* Remove the style on the other buttons */
         $(".settingButton").css('background-color','#ebeaea');
         $(".settingButton").css('font-weight','normal');

         /* Add style to clicked button */
         $(this).css('background-color','#e0e0e0');
         $(this).css('font-weight','bold');

         /* Hide the other containers, if i remove this they show when clicking. */
          $(".settingsFC").hide();

         /* Tried this one as well, didnt work */
         //$(".settingsFC:not(."+$choosenForm+")").hide();

         /* Show the right container */
         $(choosenForm).show();

    });
});​
```

Comment: The code the OP posted seemed to work just fine, so I'm not sure what you've "fixed" here. Other than hiding the `.passwordFC`, which I assume they wanted visible since they explicitly made it visible.